# click only work on second click javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you help me on this issue ?
Im trying to get  the value of the img src on click of the tag with classname downloadModal. I have tried several ways and sometimes it does work but only one the second click, and sometimes it doesn't work at all.
The tag with className downloadModal isn't in the source code and is built with javascript.
Any idea how could i get it ?
Thank u so much

THE CLICK FUNCTION

```
 //get img source name from src link
    var imageDetails = "";
    function getImageName(){
        var storage_link = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        var imageName = storage_link.split("/")[5];
        var imageName = imageName.split(".")[0];
        imageDetails = imageName;
      }
```

THE TAG CODE

```
var divImageList = document.getElementById("imageList")
  listImage.forEach(function (image) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    divImageList.appendChild(div)
    var className = ""
    model__filterList.forEach(function (typeGroup) {
      className += image[typeGroup.type] + " ";
    });
    className = "DownloadModal filterDiv" + image.id + image.className;
    div.setAttribute("class", className)
    div.setAttribute("id", "icon-all-" + image.id);
    div.setAttribute("onclick", "ctrl__openModal('" + image.id + "'); getImageName();")
```

THE DISPLAYED CODE

[image: ]]

Comment: You build the `className` string in that `.forEach` loop, but then you immediately overwrite it with another string.

Comment: is your click hander this hidden away antiquated `onclick`?  `div.setAttribute("onclick", "ctrl__openModal('" + image.id + "'); getImageName();")`?  If so, what do you do with/when do you use `imageDetails`?   Might be you're using it too soon.  Please create a [mcve] so we can see all of what you're doing.

Comment: Your `image.id` has a `#` in it, as if you were thinking of its selector. # is not ideal to use in attributes, you might have compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use `+=` to add to the class string, instead you overwrite it immediately with `=` after the loop.
This should work instead:

```js
    var className = "";
    model__filterList.forEach(function (typeGroup) {
      className += image[typeGroup.type] + " ";
    });
    className += "DownloadModal filterDiv" + image.id + image.className;
```

You also wanted to write the last statement as this I am assuming?

```js
className += "DownloadModal filterDiv " + image.id + " " + image.className;
```

It seems you forgot to add the spaces there - except this was your intention, of course.